# How to find the parent branch name of a merge commit in git?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

As asked in the title, how do I find the parent branch name (not parent commit) of a merge commit? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the merge commit is form by merging of branches

Comment: There are no parent branches in git. You *can* build a workflow where this has some meaning, but it's up to you. Same for merges. Merges are between commits, not branches, even if branches help us remember with simple names the commits we want to merge.

Comment: I see, how do I find the branches where the parent commits are located at the time of merge?

Comment: This metadata is not written by git. If you need it at some point, you'll have to enforce some specific workflow where you store the data somewhere.

Comment: I see, thanks Roman.